# Can we transfer files greater than 2GB through WCF netTcpBinding?

Tags: wcf, stream, filesize, nettcpbinding

Can we transfer files greater than 2GB through WCF netTcpBinding using Streamed mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MaxReceivedMessageSize property in the NetTcpBinding class is a `long` -  9,223,372,036,854,775,807 bytes [NetTcpBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.nettcpbinding.maxreceivedmessagesize.aspx) - that's almost 10 Terabytes (if my math is correct).

Not that is for streaming only - the 2GB limit applies for buffered mode.

See the following posts for more information:

[Maximum Size of a SOAP Message](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/drnick/archive/2006/03/16/maximum-size-of-a-soap-message.aspx)

[Making Sense of Transport Quotas](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/drnick/archive/2006/03/10/547568.aspx)

I tried but was unable to find anything in the MSDN documentation that specifically said the 10 TB limit for streamed mode, but the first link above and other posts I've seen have stated this.

Comment: You're quite welcome.  Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

why not? Have you tried this? Or do you encounter any problems?